# Pylogit Scikit-Learn Wrapper

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Is there a way to modify the pylogit syntax manually so that it is similar to the ones in scikit-learn so it can fit in an ensemble.

Is there any pylogit wrapper for scikit-learn?

Comment: Please add what you are trying to do? How do you normally do that in pylogit and what functionality of scikit do you want to work with?

Comment: Output : When defining the model : pass in the hyperparameters
When using the fit method : pass the data

Comment: Currently the data must be passed when initiating the model, then the hyperparameters passed during the fitting process